# Combine rows to create a new "other" row to reduce data size

Tags: r, ggplot2

There are 100 variables, but the screenshot only shows 22 of them. I want to be able to plot the data into a readable bar graph and with 100 variables I cannot read it well. So, I want to make an "other" row under the brand column that puts all rows into the "other" row that has a total count of less than 5. Is this possible? Or does anyone have another way of plotting 100 categorical variables into a bar plot and being able to read it? I attached a screenshot of the bar plot as well.

[image]

The image I attached is what the bar plot looks like will all 100 variables, I cannot read it.

[image]

Comment: Images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8245406) and a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit the question with the code you tried and with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (Note: `df` represents the name of your dataset.)

Answer (score 2):

If this is your data

```
set.seed(42)

df <- data.frame(brand = LETTERS[1:20], Count = sample(10, 20, replace=T))
```

Using `bind_rows` to get the modified data set

```
val <- 5

bind_rows(df %>% filter(Count >= val), 
          df %>% summarize(brand = "other", Count = sum(Count[Count < val])))
   brand Count
1      B     5
2      D     9
3      E    10
4      H    10
5      J     8
6      K     7
7      M     9
8      N     5
9      P    10
10     S     9
11     T     9
12 other    22
```

Note you can, additionally, rotate your labels to make them more readable, e.g. `... + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))`

Final plot including ordering of bars, first "other", then ascending by *Count*

```
bind_rows(df %>% filter(Count >= val), 
          df %>% summarize(brand = "other", Count = sum(Count[Count < val]))) %>%
  mutate(brand = factor(brand, levels = 
                   c(brand[grep("other", brand)], 
                     brand[grep("other", brand, invert = T)][order(Count)]))) %>%
  ggplot() + 
    geom_col(aes(brand, Count)) + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

[image: bar plot]

Answer (score 1):

I'll demonstrate how to reduce a subset of categoricals into an "other" category for plotting.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
data("starwars", package="dplyr")
ggplot(starwars, aes(eye_color)) + geom_bar()
```

[image: ggplot, too many categories]

```r
count(starwars, eye_color) %>%
  arrange(desc(n))
# # A tibble: 15 × 2
#    eye_color         n
#    <chr>         <int>
#  1 brown            21
#  2 blue             19
#  3 yellow           11
#  4 black            10
#  5 orange            8
#  6 red               5
#  7 hazel             3
#  8 unknown           3
#  9 blue-gray         1
# 10 dark              1
# 11 gold              1
# 12 green, yellow     1
# 13 pink              1
# 14 red, blue         1
# 15 white             1
count(starwars, eye_color) %>%
  mutate(eye2 = if_else(n <= 5, "other", eye_color)) %>%
  left_join(starwars, by="eye_color") %>%
  ggplot(aes(eye2)) +
  geom_bar()
```

[image: ggplot with "other" barplot]

Comment: I think the OP is asking how to create an "Other" category by count. Your method sorts and inspects the data, but ultimately categorizes based on name rather than count.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the `ifelse` to mutate the data, summarize it then plot:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- starwars
df$brand <- df$eye_color

df1 <- df %>%
  count(brand, name = 'total_count')%>%
  mutate(brand = ifelse(total_count > 5, brand, "Other"))%>%
  summarise(total_count = sum(total_count), .by = brand)
df1
#> # A tibble: 6 × 2
#>   brand  total_count
#>   <chr>        <int>
#> 1 black           10
#> 2 blue            19
#> 3 Other           18
#> 4 brown           21
#> 5 orange           8
#> 6 yellow          11

  ggplot(df1, aes(brand, total_count)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>